# Why is there no specific directory that SageMaker was supposed to create automatically?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to deploy my model (container) on AWS SageMaker. I've pushed the container to AWS ECR.
Then I use an AWS Lambda that basically runs `create_training_job()` via the `boto3` SageMaker client. It runs the container in **train** mode and puts the generated artifact to the S3. Like that:

```
sm = boto3.client('sagemaker')

sm.create_training_job(
        TrainingJobName=full_job_name,
        HyperParameters={
            'general': json.dumps(
                {
                    'environment': ENVIRONMENT,
                    'region': REGION,
                    'version': date_suffix,
                    'hyperparameter_tuning': training_params.get('hyperparameter_tuning', False),
                    'basket_analysis': training_params.get('basket_analysis', True),
                    'init_inventory_cache': training_params.get('init_inventory_cache', True),
                }
            ),
            'aws_profile': '***-dev',
            'db_config': json.dumps(database_mapping),
            'model_server_params': json.dumps(training_params.get('model_server_params', {}))
        },

        AlgorithmSpecification={
            'TrainingImage': training_image,
            'TrainingInputMode': 'File',
        },
        RoleArn=ROLE_ARN,
        OutputDataConfig={
            'S3OutputPath': S3_OUTPUT_PATH
        },
        ResourceConfig={
            'InstanceType': INSTANCE_TYPE,
            'InstanceCount': 1,
            'VolumeSizeInGB': 20,
        },
        # VpcConfig={
        #     'SecurityGroupIds': SECURITY_GROUPS.split(','),
        #     'Subnets': SUBNETS.split(',')
        # },
        StoppingCondition={
            'MaxRuntimeInSeconds': int(MAX_RUNTIME_SEC),
            #        'MaxWaitTimeInSeconds': 1800
        },
        Tags=[ ],
        EnableNetworkIsolation=False,
        EnableInterContainerTrafficEncryption=False,
        EnableManagedSpotTraining=False,
    )
```

I have a logger inside the container that says that `opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json` now exists. It has been added by SageMaker. Fine.

But then, when I try to run the same container in `serve` mode (so basically to deploy it) I encounter that `opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json` doesn't exist anymore. I deploy it this way:

```
     sm.create_model(
        ModelName=model_name,
        PrimaryContainer={
            'Image': training_image,
            'ModelDataUrl': model_artifact,
            'Environment': {
                'version': version
            }
        },
        ExecutionRoleArn=role_arn,
        Tags=[ ],
        # VpcConfig = {
        #     'SecurityGroupIds': os.environ['security_groups'].split(','),
        #     'Subnets': os.environ['subnets'].split(',')
        # }
    )

    sm.create_endpoint_config(
        EndpointConfigName=config_name,
        ProductionVariants=[
            {
                'VariantName': variant_name,
                'ModelName': model_name,
                'InitialInstanceCount': instance_count,
                'InstanceType': instance_type,
                'InitialVariantWeight': 1
            },
        ],
        Tags=[ ],
    )

    existing_endpoints = sm.list_endpoints(NameContains=endpoint_name)

    scaling_resource_id = f'endpoint/{endpoint_name}/variant/{variant_name}'

    if not existing_endpoints['Endpoints']:
        sm.create_endpoint(
            EndpointName=endpoint_name,
            EndpointConfigName=config_name
        )
    else:
        if aas.describe_scalable_targets(
                ServiceNamespace='sagemaker',
                ResourceIds=[scaling_resource_id],
                ScalableDimension='sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount')['ScalableTargets']:
            aas.deregister_scalable_target(
                ServiceNamespace='sagemaker',
                ResourceId=scaling_resource_id,
                ScalableDimension='sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount'
            )

        sm.update_endpoint(
            EndpointName=endpoint_name,
            EndpointConfigName=config_name
        )
```

It is important since it seemed to be a convenient way to pass some parameters inside the container from outside (like management console).

I thought that this file/directory will still exist after the **train**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: two options:

- Copy the `hyperparameters.json` file to `/opt/ml/model` in the training logic and it will be packed with the model artifacts;
- Pass whatever parameters you want through the `PrimaryContainer` parameter's `Environment` property.

Long version:

That file, `opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json`, (in fact the whole `/opt/ml/input` folder) is mounted on the **training** container when it is created. It is provided by SageMaker, based on information you provide, *only* for training purposes. SageMaker does not change your container in any way, and it doesn't preserve this or any configuration file it passes to the training job once training is done. If you want to pass parameters to the inference endpoint, that is not the way.

You *could* copy the `hyperparameters.json` file to the `/opt/ml/model` folder, and it'd be packed with the model in the `model.tar.gz` tarball. Your infrence code could then use that - but that's not the prescribed way to pass parameters to an endpoint, and it cause problems with your framework.

The generally prescribed way to pass parameters to SageMaker endpoints is through the **environment**. If you check the [boto3 docs for create_model](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_model), you'll see that there's an `Environment` key within the `PrimaryContainer` parameter (also for each of the `Containers` parameter). In fact, your code above already uses that to pass a `version` parameter. You should use that to pass any parameters to your model and, from there, to the endpoint based on it.